# Anyone Seen this (COM) Error Number? (80040214) When Calling .QueryStateVariable from UPnP.dll?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, upnp

*[Although I am using VB6 below, I'm happy to accept solutions in VB.NET or C#, as I can write in both]*

I am trying to use the function QueryStateVariable() which takes only one argument (a string describing the name of the variable you want to retreive the value for), so you run it like this:

```
Dim vReturn As Variant
vReturn = Service.QueryStateVariable("ExternalPort")
```

Service Object is correctly set to UPnPService (WanIPConnection). This is occuring under the WanIPConnection Service (which is directly under the Wan Connection Device), I can only read 4 out of 17 of the state variables (and I'm just using "ExternalPort" as an example variable name). Every other variable returns this error number -2147220972 (80040214) with the generic "failed" description message: Namely:

```
Run-time error '-2147220972 (80040214)':
Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService' failed
```

At the moment, I'm just ignoring it (ignoring the exception) and returning an empty string, but if anyone has any idea on what this could mean, or even just a lead I can follow up on, it would be a great help. Perhaps someone knows what this error number means or is refering to? Or, has anyone seen this or is getting this error number or has come across it before? It may have a generic meaning in the COM world, but I was unable to pinpoint it on google.

If you search google for -2147220972 there are no hits, if you remove the - sign, there are several but all pointing to different meanings, and if you put the word upnp next to it you get 0 hits! Now, if you search for "80040214 upnp" (without the quotes, of course) you get a wopping 8 hits, and that's almost entirely users running into errors using UPnP enabled software and copying/pasting their error logs. It isn't programmers reporting the error numbers and asking for help and receiving solutions or answers (would have been great).

**UPDATE:** I have found the definition of this error code, but still am no closer to solving it, as the description is very generic and doesn't provide me with any leads in how to go about resolving it, but for your information, here it is (maybe it makes more sense to some of you):

**DEFINITION OF UPNP_E_DEVICE_ERROR:**

**"The variable is not evented and the remote query returned an error code. This is not a transport error; the device received the request, but it returned an error".**

.

.

****Additional Text Written Below is Not Necessary Reading to Interpret this Question, But Included for Those Interested in Additional Information:****

I've produced a log from my program as output so I can paste the results for each of the 17 variables (and attempts to get their values) into StackOverflow. Just to recap, WanIPConnection Service has 17 variables, so I've tried and logged all of them (with only 4 successful attempts, rest are runtime errors) and the WanPPPConnection Service (which is really similar to the WanIPConnection Service) but has a total of 19 state variables (just 2 more than WanIPConnection). I have tried (and logged) all 19 variable retreival attempts and have received only 4 successful value returns (all others ending up in a runtime error) - so, I've gotten 4 successes from both the WanIPConnection and WanPPPConnection.

Here are my logs, my Real IP address changed (because I know I will get flamed if I didn't lol), and the currently set Device & Service is stated (shown) at the start of each of the two logs, here it is:

*[note to avoid confusion: I place star symbols (*) around retreived values to visualize whitespaces, sometimes StackOverflow turns the contents into italics or leaves the stars in place if string in between is empty]*

**First Log (WanIPConnection, 17 state variables):**

> Set uDevice (currently set device) to: WAN Connection Device, NETGEAR
>   WNR1000v3 N150 Wireless Router,
>   urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1
>
> Set uService (currently set service) to:
>   urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1
>
> Done GetQSV (for ConnectionStatus) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV
>   is 9 (above 0). Return value is *Connected* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for ConnectionType) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV
>   is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for ExternalIPAddress) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 13 (above 0). Return value is *110.122.16.83* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for ExternalPort) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is
>   0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for InternalClient) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV
>   is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for InternalPort) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is
>   0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for LastConnectionError) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for NATEnabled) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is 0
>   (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingDescription) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length
>   of QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingEnabled) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingLeaseDuration) in 1 (of 1) attempts.
>   Length of QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not
>   Null). [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object
>   'IUPnPService' failed LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingNumberOfEntries) in 1 (of 1) attempts.
>   Length of QSV is 1 (above 0). Return value is *2* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingProtocol) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PossibleConnectionTypes) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length
>   of QSV is 9 (above 0). Return value is *IP_Routed* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for RemoteHost) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is 0
>   (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for RSIPAvailable) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is
>   0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for Uptime) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is 0
>   (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0

**Second Log (WanPPPConnection, 19 state variables):**

> Set uDevice (currently set device) to: WAN Connection Device, NETGEAR
>   WNR1000v3 N150 Wireless Router,
>   urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1
>
> Set uService (currently set service) to:
>   urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANPPPConnection:1
>
> Done GetQSV (for DownstreamMaxBitRate) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for UpstreamMaxBitRate) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for ConnectionStatus) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV
>   is 9 (above 0). Return value is *Connected* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for ConnectionType) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV
>   is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for ExternalIPAddress) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 13 (above 0). Return value is *110.122.16.83* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for ExternalPort) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is
>   0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for InternalClient) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV
>   is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for InternalPort) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is
>   0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for LastConnectionError) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for NATEnabled) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is 0
>   (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingDescription) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length
>   of QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingEnabled) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingLeaseDuration) in 1 (of 1) attempts.
>   Length of QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not
>   Null). [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object
>   'IUPnPService' failed LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingNumberOfEntries) in 1 (of 1) attempts.
>   Length of QSV is 1 (above 0). Return value is *2* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for PortMappingProtocol) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of
>   QSV is 0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null).
>   [-2147220972] Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for PossibleConnectionTypes) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length
>   of QSV is 9 (above 0). Return value is *IP_Routed* (Not Null).
>
> Done GetQSV (for RemoteHost) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is 0
>   (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for RSIPAvailable) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is
>   0 (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0
>
> Done GetQSV (for Uptime) in 1 (of 1) attempts. Length of QSV is 0
>   (failed length check). Return value is ** (Not Null). [-2147220972]
>   Method 'QueryStateVariable' of object 'IUPnPService'
>   failed    LastDllError: 0

Comment: First up, decode the HRESULT http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT

Comment: Here is HRESULT description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088(v=vs.85).aspx Facility code in your case is `FACILITY_ITF` which means &H214 is interface specific error, it's not defined outside the interface you are using. Just look the `QueryStateVariable` documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382244(v=vs.85).aspx) under Return value section. In SDK check `UPnP.h` file, you have `#define UPNP_E_DEVICE_ERROR              MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_ERROR, FACILITY_ITF, 0x0214)` Bingo!

Comment: @wqw thanks for your help, i've done some reading on all of this btu am falling short, read the description on UPNP_E_DEVICE_ERROR, and it is very generic, saying it isn't transport related, but just that the device could not return a result. I"m not sure where to go from here, or what I should follow up on to figure out a resolution. I've looked at the upnp.h reference and the source, here is no mention of 214, i've done a ctrl+f on both pages and it's coming up with "0 matches". Should I just cut my losses on this one or do you think it is fixable?

Comment: @wqw I've found the correct source files now, I can see the descriptions and how the HRESULT error is raised & composed, however the error is very generic and provides no leads to follow up on, I'm going to keep messing around with the code to see if I can massage something out of this, but if anyone has any ideas on getting rid of this (i've read the msdn upnp docs inside out) I am totally all ears :).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan We've decoded the HRESULT to UPNP_E_DEVICE_ERROR (and I even have a description for the HRESULT, posted at end of this comment), would you have any idea what this means or how one would go about resolving it?

DEFINITION OF UPNP_E_DEVICE_ERROR:
"The variable is not evented and the remote query returned an error code. This is not a transport error; the device received the request, but it returned an error".

Comment: Maybe this error is a convoluted way to say "variable is not defined" for current device. Skip it althogether or return `Empty`/`Null` to signify "value is N/A" to UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the documentation you've already found is talking pretty clearly:

> The variable is not evented and the remote query returned an error
>   code.
>   ...
>   This method retrieves the values of evented variables from the
>   service object's local cache. The cache contains the value for each
>   variableindicated in the last event notification.

A quick look into UPnP spec of `InternetGateway.WANIPConnection` confirms that the variables you're failing on, are indeed **not evented**. Which means that "service object's local cache" cannot contain any value for those variables. Device simply didn't provide any. **The variables which you are successfuly obtaining are only the evented ones**.

The Microsoft doc even says in "Remarks" section:

> The UPnP Forum discourages use of this method. If possible, use
>   a service-specific action, if one has been provided.

"A service specific action" is mostly named "Get[TheVariableName]". I am not familiar with this specific SCPD, but a second quick look into the UPnP spec yields:

```
ConnectionType = GetConnectionTypeInfo
ExternalPort,InternalClient,InternalPort = GetGenericPortMappingEntry
LastConnectionError = GetStatusInfo
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input, from what I gather (and as you've stated) the variables are obsolete and performing the Action's are the new/preferred standard to get the values for those variables. Therefore, the new UPnP spec discourages using local variables when there is an Action replacement. Correct me if I am wrong anywhere. Up voted & Accepted, thanks again.